# iPhone 5s, how do I clear my App Store cache?

Tags: ios

How do I clear my App Store cache? Since my latest update/upgrade to my phone the apps no longer say if they are free or what they cost. Tried to download an app on the fly one day (not realizing it was a $49.99 app!). The card I keep on my iTunes account only has $5 on so my kids don't download anything ridiculous (or in this case myself either!) So my problem is, the App Store will not let me update my current apps or download new free apps without finishing the purchase of the "accidental" app... Any advice on how to get rid of it?

Comment: The purchase record is at Apple, not on the phone - you'd have to ring them

Comment: Does it help to log out and log in again? (At the bottom of the "Highlights" page click on the Apple ID button. Additionally you may have to quit the App Store app after this log out.)